# Why is it impossible to assign to a vector of objects that themselves lack copy operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stdvector

I have a vector of structures that are copy-constructible, but non-assignable:

```
struct Struct
{
    inline Struct(const std::string& text, int n) : _text(text), _n(n) {}
    inline Struct(const Struct& other) : _text(other._text), _n(other._n) {}

    const std::string _text;
    const int _n;

    Struct& operator=(const Struct&) = delete;
};
```

It all worked fine. In fact, I could even pass the `std::vector<Struct>` around by value as a return value of a function. And yet, this fails:

```
std::vector<TextFragment> v1, v2;
v2 = v1;
```

The error, of course, is:

> error: C2280: 'Struct &Struct ::operator =(const Struct &)' :
>   attempting to reference a deleted function

I don't understand why it tries to invoke that. Is that some kind of an optimization to avoid re-allocating the vector's memory block?..

Comment: I don't see your copy constructor. It should be `Struct(const Struct &other)`.

Comment: @Fozi: Good point. I assume I'd get the default one, but it was before I added my 2 arguments constructor. Let me check.

Comment: @Fozi: nope, that did not help.

Comment: Deleting a function doesn't remove it from overload resolution. So naturally calling a deleted function results in an error. Or is your question why you can't copy something that isn't copyable?

Comment: @sleeptightpupper: the question must be clear enough since the others get it.

Comment: It doesn't make a whole lot of sense to have a class that is copy-constructable but not copy-assignable (is it copyable or not?)...

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Seems perfectly reasonable to me. Copy-construction just means "I will copy the other thing and then exist", copy-assignment is "I will become the other thing". Consider an immutable property-bag class.

Comment: @GManNickG: No, copy-assignment is "I will copy this other thing, replacing my previous state".  An immutable object is just `const` -- independent of any constructors or assignment operators.  Of course, C++ has no good way of expressing "all instances of this class should be const", but it's not that clear to me that makes a lot of sense either.  "I will become this other thing" is move construction/assignment,

Comment: @ChrisDodd You just classified all lambdas as making no sense :)

Comment: @M.M Assuming that you mean destroy + recreate in place, that doesn't work with `const`-qualified things (see [basic.life]/8).

Comment: @T.C.: well yes, the way lambdas are defined in the C++ standard is fairly non-sensical, and the deleted copy assignment operator is just one part of that.

Comment: @T.C. OK. So the workaround has to be not using `const` members in the first place then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is that some kind of an optimization to avoid re-allocating the vector's memory block?..

Almost.  It is an optimization to avoid re-allocating whatever memory blocks might be present in `vector`'s `value_type`.  That is, it is a global assumption that assignment can be more efficient than destruction followed by copy construction.

For example consider `vector<string>` assignment, for two equal sized `vector`s, and a bunch of equal sized `string`s in each spot in the `vector`:

```
v2 = v1;
```

All this operation has to do is `memcpy` each `string`.  No allocations at all.  Reducing allocations/deallocations is one of the most important optimizations that exist today.

However, all is not lost for your `Struct`.  What you want to do is instruct the `vector` that you do not wish to assign your `Struct`s, but instead destruct them, and then copy construct them from `v1`.  The syntax for doing this is:

```
v2.clear();
for (const auto& x : v1)
    v2.push_back(x);
```

As noted in the comments below, you can also copy construct `v1`,  and then `swap` with the copy.  You either need to create a temporary local copy of `v1`, or you need to use `v1` on the "lhs" of member swap:

```
std::vector<Struct>(v1).swap(v2);
```

I personally find this hard to read.  In C++11/14 I prefer this alternative which involves move assignment:

```
v2 = std::vector<Struct>(v1);
```

These alternatives are easier on the eyes.  But the first alternative, using `clear()` and `push_back` is going to be the most efficient on average.  This is because the first alternative is the only one that has a chance of reusing `capacity()` in `v2`.  The other two *always* recreate new `capacity()` in the copy of `v1` and throw away `v2`'s existing `capacity()`.

Comment: The first answer that actually answers my question, and makes sense. Thank you! 
"Reducing allocations/deallocations is one of the most important optimizations that exist today." - I shall remember that.

Comment: Somehow I did not think of copying it the way you suggested. But I did think about this, though, and it works: `v2.swap(std::vector<Struct>(v1));`

Comment: why not `v2.clear(); v2.insert(v2.begin(), v1.begin(), v1.end());` to safe on the conditional logic inside `push_back()`?

Comment: @TemplateRex:  `vector<T>::insert` requires `T` to be MoveAssignable (and in this particular example, CopyAssignable as well), which `Struct` is not.

Comment: Hm, that seems like a gap in the vector interface. I find it surprising that there is no ranged in-place construct member (apart from the constructor). Do you know of any proposals on this?

Comment: @TemplateRex:  I am not aware of any proposals in this area at the moment.  I question that such a proposal would be successful.   In the no-reallocation case, `vector::insert` must "make a hole" to put the new element in.  This "hole" is a constructed but moved from `value_type`.  In the process of making this hole, `value_type` will be move assigned (say from the "hole" to v[hole+1]).  This is true before we even start to talk about how to fill in the hole with the newly inserted element(s).

Comment: I was thinking of bypasing `insert` altogether with a member `construct(first, last)`, similar to the ranged  `assign` member. It would simply call the allocator::construct in a loop, with a single capacity check upfront.

Comment: @TemplateRex:  This would also be easy to write yourself as a namespace scope function (using `clear`, `distance`, `reserve`, and `push_back`).

Comment: Sure, but `push_back` will still have per-element conditional logic to check for within-capacity (branch prediction has its limits). A class-member could bypass that and do `clear`, `distance` and then a loop doing in-place construction (through the allocator's `construct`). I think it would be nice if every `vector` member that works on single elements (such as `push_back`) had a ranged-counterpart with the same type requirements that could amortize all the allocation overhead and eliminate duplicated conditional logic. AFAICS, there is no such member for `push_back`.

Comment: A paper with timing comparisons would be interesting to read.

Answer (score 3):

A `std::vector` is a allocator-aware container.  If we look at the spec for that(table 99) we have `a = t` where `a` is a non-const lvalue and `t` is a lvalue or const rvalue and it requires

> T is CopyInsertable into X and **CopyAssignable**. post: a == t

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

Where `T` is the `value_type` of `X`(the container).  It also states that the operation is linear.  Since `T` needs to be [CopyAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable) and `Struct` is not CopyAssignable it is not required to work.

This implies that the assignment operation would look something like:

```
std::vector<T>& operator=(const std::vector<T>& rhs)
{
    // allocate enough room for data if needed
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < rhs.size(); ++i)
        data[i] = rhs.data[i];
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: more likely to take `rhs` by const reference (and have separate move-assignment operator)

Comment: I don't think "allocate" and "room" are the correct words here. It's more like "construct enough targets".

Comment: This example is overly simplified and doesn't even use the allocator, making it a non-sequitor.

Comment: Moot point. Re-allocating the memory and using placement new for items would also be linear complexity, and would not rely on assignment. In fact, I'm not even sure re-allocation would be strictly necessary.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe I updated the answer a little.  The point is the standard mandates that `T` must be copyAssignable.

Comment: So does it specifically say that `T` must only be CopyAssignable for vector assignment to work, but not in order to construct the vector and insert elements?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe It says it has to be CopyInsertable and CopyAssignable.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this function informative, from libc++. In particular, note the call to `std::copy`.

```
template <class _Tp, class _Allocator>
template <class _ForwardIterator>
typename enable_if
<
    __is_forward_iterator<_ForwardIterator>::value &&
    is_constructible<
       _Tp,
       typename iterator_traits<_ForwardIterator>::reference>::value,
    void
>::type
vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::assign(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last)
{
    size_type __new_size = static_cast<size_type>(_VSTD::distance(__first, __last));
    if (__new_size <= capacity())
    {
        _ForwardIterator __mid = __last;
        bool __growing = false;
        if (__new_size > size())
        {
            __growing = true;
            __mid =  __first;
            _VSTD::advance(__mid, size());
        }
        pointer __m = _VSTD::copy(__first, __mid, this->__begin_);
        if (__growing)
            __construct_at_end(__mid, __last, __new_size - size());
        else
            this->__destruct_at_end(__m);
    }
    else
    {
        deallocate();
        allocate(__recommend(__new_size));
        __construct_at_end(__first, __last, __new_size);
    }
}
```

`operator =` just calls `assign(r.begin(), r.end())` after fixing up the allocator if they differ.